# Codeigniter 4 advanced image routing issue

Tags: codeigniter, image-processing, codeigniter-4

I converted the Codeigniter 3 advanced image library to Codeigniter 4 but the Route is not working

Codeigniter 3 route = $route['public/image/(:any)'] = 'media/resize/$1';

Codeigniter 4 route = $routes->get('public/image/(:any)', 'Media::resize/$1');

what is the point?

Comment: Can you get any routes to work?

Comment: $routes->get('/', 'Media::resize/$1'); this work fine but
this $routes->get('public/image/(:any)', 'Media::resize/$1') does not work

Answer (score 1):

Solved

Change htaccess:

RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|public|robots.txt|ads.txt|images|stylesheets|scripts|robots.txt)

to

RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|robots.txt|ads.txt|images|stylesheets|scripts|robots.txt)